# How to One-Hot value in one column where it contains multiple value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, etl, data-manipulation

How do i split the values into column and set 1 to the record if it contains the value

data-set creation

```
   df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": ['1-1-2019', '1-2-2019'],
    "data": ['abc,bcd','abc,efg,hij'],
    "Others" :['Other column info','Other column info']
})
```

Original data

```
    date       data          Others
  1-1-2019     abc,bcd       Other column info
  1-2-2019     abc,efg,hij   Other column info
```

Expected result

```
    date     abc   bcd  efg   hij   Others
   1-1-2019   1     1    0     0    Other column info
   1-2-2019   1     0    1     1    Other column info
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use get_dummies function of dataframes str methods like below

```py
pd.concat([df, df.data.str.get_dummies(sep=",")], axis=1)
```